# Convert array of object to string in TDE template

Tags: marklogic

in the documents with which I work I have an array of objects that I want to pass without any modification, is it possible and sensible to convert such an object to a string via TDE?

```
{
    "Addr": [
        {
            "AddrTypeCd": "MailingAddress",
            "Addr1": "911 FORBES AVE",
            "Addr2": "SUITE XXX",
            "CityName": "asdfasfd",
            "StateProvCd": "PA",
            "PostalCode": "15219"
        },
        {
            "AddrTypeCd": "OfficeAddress",
            "Addr1": "911 Watson AVE",
            "Addr2": "SUITE XXX",
            "CityName": "asdfasfd",
            "StateProvCd": "CT",
            "PostalCode": "15119"
        }
    ]
}
```

Result value should look like below:

```
"{
    "Addr": [
        {
            "AddrTypeCd": "MailingAddress",
            "Addr1": "911 FORBES AVE",
            "Addr2": "SUITE XXX",
            "CityName": "asdfasfd",
            "StateProvCd": "PA",
            "PostalCode": "15219"
        },
        {
            "AddrTypeCd": "OfficeAddress",
            "Addr1": "911 Watson AVE",
            "Addr2": "SUITE XXX",
            "CityName": "asdfasfd",
            "StateProvCd": "CT",
            "PostalCode": "15119"
        }
    ]
}"
```

Is such a conversion possible at all without FLWOR statements?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string value that you would like to produce from this array? For instance, are you just looking to have the text values concatenated, so they can be searched or do you want the field names included as part of that string value?

Comment: Field names should be included as a part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `xdmp:quote($parent)`.

Comment: I am curious if this will work. The list of data transformation functions supported in TDE template does not include `xdmp:quote`: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_51421